# Why won't ActionResult<T> accept a T instance that implements IActionResult?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

The definition of `ActionResult<T>` is:

```
public sealed class ActionResult<TValue> : IConvertToActionResult
{...}
```

and it has this constructor:

```
public ActionResult(TValue value)
{
    if (typeof(IActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TValue)))
    {
        var error = Resources.FormatInvalidTypeTForActionResultOfT(typeof(TValue), "ActionResult<T>");
        throw new ArgumentException(error);
    }

    Value = value;
}
```

Why would it be an issue for 'TValue' to implement this interface? What `ActionResult<T>` does can be understood from the code, but I cannot understand the reason for this check and the need to throw an exception.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6101

Comment: Kirk Larkin thanks for this. I'm a big confused though. I find it strange that the asp.net team felt the need to put in a type check to make a particular scenario impossible. I understand what the type is meant to accomplish but I don't understand the problem or the antipattern that they're protecting against. What harm would it do? "That's not how it's meant to be used" is OK, putting a check for it into the implementation is something else.